# What is the Video Format for Asus Transformer?

Tags: android, converters, movie, avi, transformer-model

I have an Asus Transformer and would like to put a lot of movies in it. However, it seems like it's very hard to find the proper format for it.

I've tried to convert the movies both in AVI and MP4 format where video codec is either MPEG4/H264/H263/XVID and audio codec is either MP3/AAC/AC3/PCM. However, despite many alternatives, none of them works and I am going insane right now.

At the moment, I have 2 720p movies that can be played and they are AVI with XVID codec. I tried to convert a movie with the same format container and video codec (AVI with XVID) but it does not work.

Do I need a special converter to make it work? Everything is just really weird.

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: you have accepted 24 questions but didnot accept any of answers. Go and first accept correct answers then expect answer of your questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you try this: http://www.pavtube.com/dvd_ripper/ to convert the files into android .mp4 format?

Comment: That one is actually might work well with DVD. But all of my movies are either in mp4 or mkv. So i need a converter instead of ripper. Thanks anyway though for the suggestion.

Comment: Pavtube is a known spammer and [GPL violator](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4239).